# My userdetails array is showing undefined therefore it is not rendering in map

Tags: arrays, reactjs, axios, undefined, mern

I consoled log and added comment inside render(). How can I make it defined so that in modal body it will render users username?

This are my console log output [] SearchModal.js:37 undefined this is for that userdetails line just after render SearchModal.js:53 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SearchUser } from '../services/SearchService';
import {Modal} from 'react-bootstrap';

class SearchModal extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        show: false,
        search: '',
        userdetails:[]
    }

    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    this.onTextboxChangeSearch = this.onTextboxChangeSearch.bind(this);
}

handleShow() {
    this.setState({ show: true })
}
handleClose(){
    this.setState({ show: false })
}

onTextboxChangeSearch(event) {
  const { value } = event.target;
  this.setState({
    search: value // <-- (1) update state
  });
}


SearchForUser = async () => { // <-- (3) refactored search function
  const { search, userdetails } = this.state;
  const {data} = { username: search };
  console.log(data)

  const { user } = await SearchUser(data);
  this.setState({ userdetails: user });
  console.log(userdetails)
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.search !== this.state.search) {
    this.SearchForUser(); // <-- (2) search state updated, do search for user
  }
}
render() {
    let {search,userdetails}= this.state;
    console.log(userdetails)  //showing undefined
    return (<Modal.Body>
               <h3>Users</h3>
               <div>
                <ul className="collection">
                  {userdetails && userdetails.map((element,i) => {
                    <li key={i}>{element.username}</li>
                  })}
                </ul>
               </div>
             </Modal.Body>)
```

Comment: Try removing brackets from `const {data}`. And probably from `const { user }` too. You may want to learn more about  destructuring assignment syntax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: TypeError: userdetails.map is not a function  then this err is coming

Comment: If you do `const searchResponse = await SearchUser({username: search }); console.log(searchResponse );` what will it print? can you try and add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: its logging userdetails

Comment: even console.log({element }) is logging inside map element: {_id: "602d50fb11d7500428c270b8", username: "abc", email: "abc@gmail.com"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed {user} to user and same with data.

It's working now, I added this return statement:

```
return(li key={i}>{element.username}</li>);
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(user)` try to console user first  inside SearchForUser function

Comment: logging  userdetails _id: "602d50fb11d7500428c270b8", username: "abc", email: "abc@gmail.com"}

Comment: even console.log({element }) is logging inside map element: {_id: "602d50fb11d7500428c270b8", username: "abc", email: "abc@gmail.com"}